# Selenium Webdriver: Element Not Visible Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Here is my code to click a simple login button on this [Website](https://platform.drawbrid.ge/)

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;    

public class Reports {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://platform.drawbrid.ge");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='_loginButton']")).click();

    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Command duration or timeout: 2.05 seconds

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two buttons with given xpath on this page, first is not visible, thats why you are getting ElementNotVisibleException

One is under `<div class="loginPopup">`

Second (the one you need) is under `<div class="page">`

So change your xpath to look like this, and it will fix your problem:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='page']//div[@id='_loginButton']")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are even 3 elements with `id="_loginButton"` on the page, and *only one is visible* - the one located inside the login form, you can get it by a *CSS selector*:

```
By.cssSelector("form#_loginForm div#_loginButton")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 occurrences of `id="_loginButton"`.

Used the `id="_loginButton"` under `class="signIn"` by cssSelector to get the exact button in the page.

```
By.cssSelector("div.signIn div#_loginButton")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Webdriver` may throw an `ElementNotVisible` exception in-case there are multiple elements with the same locator and if `Webdriver` has already operated upon one of the element matching the locator.

In such scenarios you can first get the size of the element using

```
int var_ele_size= driver.findElements(By.xpath("locator")).size();
```

and then take the first element from the list and click on the element.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("locator")).get(var_ele_size-1).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Listget (WebDriver driver) throws Exception 

{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    UtilityMethod.getAppLocaters(driver, "closeicon").click();

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='parent dropdown  aligned-left']"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();

    List<WebElement>links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='menu-title']"));
    int total_count = links.size();       
    System.out.println("Total size :=" +total_count);           
     for(int i=0;i<total_count;i++)
        {             
            WebElement  element = links.get(i);
            String text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            System.out.println("linksnameis:="  +text);

            try{
                    File src = new File("D:ReadFile.xlsx");
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
                    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                    XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);

                    sh.createRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue(text);

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/ReadFile.xlsx"));
                    wb.write(fos);
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I getting error "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible"
Need help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your window on the `remote server` is big enough so the elements are not hidden because of space constraints ..

This worked for me: (I use `c#`)

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1928, 1060);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your locator value")));
```

Or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.xpath("your locator value")));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer - please try to add more context around the answers provided - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer