# Element cannot be sent to a field, website login, Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, field, hidden

I used below scripts to log into the following website with a username and password. It used to work fine. However, I think recently Etsy set the username ( and maybe password too) to hidden type. So username cannot be sent to the Email address field. Here are the scripts. Anyone knows how to fix this particular case?

The error message is:

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Python27/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)    
self.driver.get("https://www.etsy.com/signin") 

usernameFieldID = "username"
passFieldID = "password"
signButtonXpath = "//input[@value='Sign in']"

usernameFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_name(usernameFieldID))

passFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_name(passFieldID))

signButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_xpath(signButtonXpath))

usernameFieldElement.send_keys("abc@abc.com")
passFieldElement.send_keys("EtsyPass")
signButtonElement.click()
```

Comment: I am quite new to Python and post questions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide information about specific error you get like stacktrace of the error.

Comment: That's right. The error message is :ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver: Element Not Visible Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820820/selenium-webdriver-element-not-visible-exception)

Comment: Have you tried it without the `WebDriverWait(driver,5)`?

Comment: @Joe T. Boka - tried.

Comment: @LilyJ, so, how is going? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

For the Button not being clicked, there are two possible reasons making your script fails.

1. Timing:

I suppose that the button is disabled until both email and password are filled. That makes that you have to wait till the button is enabled. To test if this is the reason of failure you can put sleep just before clicking on the button.

2. Your locator is not unique:

Did you check using, for instance, Chrome Developer tools that your locator for the submit button is unique? If not, another element (not visible on your page) is maybe clicked.

How to do this you can learn here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMk7ZLuo6Po.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a certain factors as follows :

- As the fields/elements pertaining to **Email address**, **Password** and **Sign in** button is on the same page, you don't have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) for all the individual fields. Inducing *WebDriverWait* on the first field will provide ample time for all the elements to be interactive within the *HTML DOM*.
- As you will be working with multiple elements on the *Web Page* instead of `until(lambda)` you need to get more granular with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)
- Down the lane as you are trying to invoke `send_keys("foo")` you can consider using `expected_conditions` as **`element_to_be_clickable`**.
- Here is the working code :

  ```
  self.driver.get("https://www.etsy.com/signin") 
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input input-large ' and @id='join_neu_email_field']"))).send_keys("abc@abc.com")
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='input input-large ' and @id='join_neu_password_field']").send_keys("EtsyPass")
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-large width-full btn-primary' and @name='submit_attempt']").click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with my original code by adding

time.sleep(5) after the click button command was executed.

I think Chrome takes time to feed in the login ID and password. Without the extra time, the next line was executed without logging in yet.

Thanks everyone, for your handy tips.